# Making a 2D array of generic lists in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, 2d

So - I want to make a 2D array of generic lists containing some data I am interested in (on a grid of of some set size),

```
private ArrayList<MyDataStruct>[][] gridData;
```

When I initialize this array, I go,

```
gridData = (ArrayList<MyDataStruct>[][])new ArrayList[w][h];
for(int x=0; x<w; x++)
    for(int y=0; y<h; y++){
        gridData[x][y] = (ArrayList<MyDataStruct>)new ArrayList<MyDataStruct>(0);
        //other stuff, i.e. get data from somewhere, etc
    }
```

and I get a `unchecked cast` warning.  Was curious about why this is not type safe and what I can do to make it type safe (short of switching out of using a 2d array).  I understand that it's not very good to mix arrays and generics, but in this case I'm just writing this to run some experiments, so i'm using this instead of say lists of lists lists to save myself some time.  Are there any other more elegant approaches that let's me get away with easy to read/write syntax (i.e. no nested lists), but are also type safe?

Thanks!

Comment: @assylias: Because that doesn't compile.  Not even close.  Generics and arrays just don't work like that in Java.

Answer (score 2):

The only type-safe option is to use nested lists.

Because of type erasure, you can't do `new ArrayList<MyDataStruct>[w][h]`, because that basically becomes `new ArrayList[w][h]`...and things get complicated and hairy, fast, because arrays *don't* behave like generics.

Java considers `String[]` to be a subclass of `Object[]`, but `ArrayList<String>` isn't a subclass of `ArrayList<Object>`.  Normally, arrays throw an `ArrayStoreException` when you try to put an element into an array that doesn't match the array's true type, but because of type erasure, it can't do that when generics are in the picture.

Josh Bloch gives the following example in Effective Java:

```
// Why generic array creation is illegal - won't compile!
List<String>[] stringLists = new List<String>[1];
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(42);
Object[] objects = stringLists;
objects[0] = intList;
String s = stringLists[0].get(0);
```

The only way to prevent all this code from being entirely legal in Java is to ban the generic array creation, or at least mark it as unsafe.

That said, IMO, the moderate overhead of typing out `List` and doing it with generic lists is absolutely worth the type safety.

Comment: So I guess I'll be stuck with the warning as long as I use arrays?  It's "safe" in the sense that I know what I'm suppose to put and get out of it.  But tbh, I can't even think of a situation where my code would be type-unsafe (so you mean if I decided to put a list in my 2d array that wasn't of generic type MyDataStruct, Java would unable to figure this out?).

Comment: That's more or less correct.  I added an example from Josh Bloch's Effective Java, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got here with the same problem (just some experiments, "get things done" approach).
Here is a solution that seems to work for me, using reflection.

note that it is 100% agnostic to the type of the cells in the array (can be list, map, anything). perhaps with a little more work it can also be agnostic to the # of dimensions of the array, but I've bigger fish to fry today...

```
private static <T>  T[][] makeArray(Class<T> componentType, int... dimentions) {
    return (T[][]) Array.newInstance(componentType, dimentions);
}
```

attached below is a test method. to keep the type of the array generic I had to ugly-cast here. this can be handled in another wrapping method to keep client code nice and clean:

```
@Test
public void testMakeArray() throws Exception {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String>[][] arr = makeArray(List.class, 2, 3);

    Assert.assertEquals(2, arr.length);
    Assert.assertEquals(3, arr[0].length);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = Arrays.asList("cell", "r="+i, "c="+j);
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

it prints:

```
[cell, r=0, c=0]    [cell, r=0, c=1]    [cell, r=0, c=2]    
[cell, r=1, c=0]    [cell, r=1, c=1]    [cell, r=1, c=2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with a similar idea, but instead used nested Lists of Optionals. It seems to provide some benefits as you do not need to check for null and can instead use isEmpty or isPresent for each cell. However, I'm sure for reasons unknown to me, this is probably not a great solution. I thought i'd share anyways.

```
public class Grid<T> {
    private final int rowCount;
    private final int columnCount;
    private final List<List<Optional<T>>> data;

    public Grid(int rowCount, int columnCount) {
        this.rowCount = rowCount;
        this.columnCount = columnCount;
        data = build();
    }

    private List<List<Optional<T>>> build() {
        return IntStream.range(0, rowCount)
                .mapToObj(rowId -> IntStream.range(0, columnCount)
                        .mapToObj(columnId -> Optional.<T>empty())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public Optional<T> get(int rowId, int columnId) {
        return data.get(rowId).get(columnId);
    }

    public void set(int rowId, int columnId, T t) {
        data.get(rowId).set(columnId, Optional.ofNullable(t));
    }
}
```